# How can I load a massive data file in Java? Any structure better than hashtables?

Tags: java, file, data-structures, hashtable

I am trying to load a big file of 14 million lines in hashtables in the memory. Each line contains three numbers (n,m,v), where:

- n: is the id of a user (an object)
- m: is the id of an item (an object)
- v: is the rate that user n gives to the item m.

Each user `n` has a `hashtable<item, rate>` to store the items that the user rates, 
and each item has a `hashtable<user, rate>` to store the users that rated this item.

On my machine I cannot load this structure into the memory so I have a heap memory error in every time.

I tried to replace hashtables with hashBasedTable, which allows tow keys for each value, but no solution. In addition hashBasedTable made my program much slower.

Is there any solution to be able to load this mass of data?

Comment: For this volume of data you should certainly be using a database.

Comment: Did you try setting your maximum heap size (the `-Xmx` argument)?

Comment: No, you didn't. See [Eugene's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13105999/3474) and my comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you represent each rated item's users and each user's rated items using `ArrayList<User>` and `ArrayList<Item>` respectively.  That will save a lot of space.

Admittedly, some operations will now be `O(N)` but that is only a problem if `N` gets large.  (And if it does, consider a hybrid where you use `ArrayList` for small relations and `HashMap` for large ones.)

Suggestion #2 - use plain arrays ... and keep them sorted so that you can implement lookup using binary search.  This is more code intensive (i.e. more complicated), but it will give you better memory usage than using Collection types.

Suggestion #3 - Use a database.  It will scale better.

Comment: The problem about ArrayLists in this context is that I need to save values too, I use for rated items a hashtable<Item, Double> where Double is the value of the note that the user has given to this item.
Using lists I'll need two one to stock the items and one to stock the notes.
I also tried to have an independent class that contains references to the rater, the rated items, and the note value but this was very slow.

Answer (score 2):

14 millions lines of three numbers each doesn't sound like a massive data array. 
It is approximately 14M * (3 + 1) * 8 ~ 450M or memory.

Just make sure you set -Xmx setting to a big enough value (e.g. -Xmx1024m - which will allow JVM allocate up to 1G of RAM).

P.S. I would suggest `HashMap` instead of `HashTable` though.

Comment: Addressing OP's comment on a similiar, but unfortunately deleted answer: The eclipse.ini settings only apply to Eclipse itself, not to programs that you launch from Eclipse. For that, you need to change the setting listed above in the `Run...` dialog. +1 for this. 14 million records is nothing. $14 million, on the other hand...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it depends on the data structure you use. You simply cannot load so much data into RAM, you would have to process the file line by line and execute the logic you have.

Comment: The "raw" amount of data is well under a gigabyte. You would be hard-pressed to find a computer with under a gig of memory these days.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Still I would not load this kind of amount of data into the memory. What if his file grows to more than 1 GB in the future?

Comment: @Jagger: put it on two computers.  If the access pattern really is random, you're hosed if it is kept on disk (RAM~100ns, disk~10ms).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear as to your access pattern, but it sounds like you probably want to use a single big table instead of one per user and per item.  Especially if your data is very sparse (only a few items per user or vice versa), you will be wasting a lot of space due to the initial capacity of the hashtables (you could try lowering the initial capacity and/or raising the load factor if you wanted to keep your current organization).

Build a pair object (user id, item id) to use as the key for a single big hashtable.  If you need enumeration (i.e. list all items for a user or vice versa), keep `ArrayList`s of that data and use `trimToSize`, much more compact than a hashtable.

Comment: I tried to have this single big table using HashBasedTable, but it took hours to fill that table when I execute my program

Comment: Don't use `HashBasedTable`, it has the same problem with your implementation (it is a two-level table).  Use `HashMap` with a pair object as the key.